# Confirm resistor and transistor for amp fix

Tags: transistors, amplifier, resistors, repair

I got the magic smoke on day 2 of using an 80s Yamaha A-500. Thought it was the large electrolytic caps as they'd leaked but on replacing them with Nichicon ones, the smoke continued on powering up again. It's my first amp fix, but it is a bucket list thing. I have nobody local to ask for advice so hopefully a kind soul out there can assist.

I've found the source of the smoke, these circled resistors. And I'm guessing it's the two transistors nearby that could be the cause. TR116 and 118. I have a photo of the resistors pre-burn, giving indication of values, but can't tell for sure from the service manual circuit diagram and parts list which resistor it is. Transistor more straightforward, 2SA999. Assuming these are the ones feeding the resistors. It's not clear from the photos, but the ones under the lowest of the 3 big resistors, to left of cap, in the rectangle outline, above transistor 118 - not the first one above it though, the pair above that. They are now black so thankfully this photo can assist in confirming values. Hopefully.

Any other checks I can do without desoldering? Only have a cheap 25W iron and I am not the neatest with it.

Further info: the amp worked well pre-burnout, apart from crackling and right/left drop out when turning the volume knob. I supposed it was the big caps. Attaching photos and screenshots of service manual.

[image: To left of smaller cap, under lower of bigger resistors]

[image: Detail of pre burnout resistors]

[image: Transistor as per circuit diagram]

[image: Resistor?]

[image: Screenshot of pdf at best Res I have]

Comment: Crackling while changing volume is due to a worn or cheap potentiometer. A new, quality potentiometer should fix that.

Comment: I have to ask - have you soldered the big electrolytics with wrong polarity? Just to be sure as the cap stripe is usually the negative side and there seems to be a + sign near the cap stripe mark.

Comment: @Justme I don't think so as they are the L shape layout ones and only go in one way. Couldn't see any obvious plus or minus symbols. Just followed old electrolytics layout.

Comment: @Math Keeps Me Busy - thanks for the lead. I have seen the idle voltage setting components but would it make sense to test them, or any other parts, before stripping and replacing?

Comment: Wrong forum brother.   Take this to a guitar amplifier site.   Try https://www.thegearpage.net/board/index.php?forums/amps-cabs-tech-corner-amplifier-cab-speakers.11/

Comment: It's not that kind of amp, @Kyle B! Would have thought the electronics forum of SE would be the place for help with electronics?

Comment: SOrry I just assumed  LOL   Yamaha makes alotta guitar amps....

Comment: No worries, should have made it clearer! At least when I was growing up, every EE I met had fixed or made their own audio gear. Was always a bucket list project of mine to fix an amp, and one fell into my lap! Hoping this one isn't beyond a few simple swap outs.

Comment: Use the "diode" setting on your multimeter to verify that the output transistors (or any others) are not shorted. This is a very common fault. The meter's diode setting forces a small current and displays the voltage. This is a good way to locate shorted transistors. You're aware that Bipolar transistors each have a pair of PN junctions, right? Check both. You're looking for approx 0..6V when they are forward biased. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Randy, will do that - just struggling to figure out the colours of the resistor pair under the 1.8kOhm resistor here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3p8Z.jpg - I see are Red, Grey/Blue, Black, Brown, Gold, which would make the pair each a 2.8k ohm resistor. I'm reading it that way assuming that's gold at the end. But I don't see that in the parts list or on the circuit layout. But these are the ones that are now black!